# Closed form for $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^2+u^2}\tanh(x) \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form, complex-integration

solve

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^2+u^2}\tanh(x) dx:0<n<2$$

I tried for $n=1$ :

$$I(v)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+u^2}\tanh(vx) dx$$

$$I'(v)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\cosh^2(vx)}-\frac{u^2}{(x^2+u^2)\cosh^2(vx)}) dx$$

$$I'(v)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ku^{-2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^{2k}}{\cosh^2(vx)})dx$$

$$I'(v)=-\frac{1}{v}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k(uv)^{-2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^{2k}}{\cosh^2(x)})dx$$

and i solved the last integral in term of zeta function but i failed to find the result of sum .

I interested to find the result of sum.

---

If you can find for $n=1$ and for general n ?

using two method complex and real :)

Comment: It converges only for $n\in(-2,1)$.

Comment: Maybe,
$$
\tanh\left(\,x\,\right)
=x\sum_{k\ =\ -\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \left[\left(\,2k + 1\,\right)\pi/2\,\right]^{\,\,2} + x^{2}}
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin , I think that should solve the question.

Answer (score 10):

As Lucian stated in the comments above, the integral converges only if $-2 < n <1$.

I'll do the case $n=-1$ using contour integration.

For $u>0$ and not equal to $\pi \left(k + \frac{1}{2} \right)$ (where $k$ is a nonnegative integer),  consider the complex function

$$ f(z) = \frac{\tanh z}{u^{2}+z^{2}} \frac{1}{z}.$$

Integrating the function $f(z)$ around a rectangular contour in the upper half-plane of height $K \pi$ and then letting $K \to \infty$ discretely, we find

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\tanh x}{(u^{2}+x^{2})} \, \frac{dx}{x} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh x}{(u^{2}+x^{2})} \, \frac{dx}{x} \\ &= \pi i \left(\text{Res}[f(z), iu]   + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \text{Res}\left[f(z), i \pi \left(k+\frac{1}{2} \right)\right] \right) \end{align}$$

where

$$ \text{Res}[f(z), iu]  = \lim_{z \to iu} \frac{\tanh z}{z+iu} \frac{1}{z} = \frac{\tanh (iu)}{2iu} \frac{1}{iu} = \frac{\tan u}{2iu^{2}}$$

and

$$  \begin{align} \text{Res}\left[f(z), i \pi \left(k+\frac{1}{2} \right)\right] &= \lim_{z \to i \pi (k+1/2)} \frac{\sinh z}{\frac{d}{dz} (u^{2}+z^{2})z \cosh z } \\ &= \frac{1}{i \pi} \frac{1}{\left( (u^{2}-\pi^{2}(k+ \frac{1}{2})^{2} \right)  (k + \frac{1}{2})} \\ &= - \frac{1}{i \pi^{3}}  \frac{1}{\left(k- \frac{u}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\left(k + \frac{u}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \left(k + \frac{1}{2} \right)} . \end{align}$$

In general, $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+a)(k+b)(k+c)}= \frac{(b-c) \ \psi(a)+ (c-a) \ \psi(b)+(a-b) \ \psi(c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$

where $a \ne b$, $b \ne c$, $c \ne a$, and $a, b, c \ne 0, -1, -2, \ldots$ .

Here $\psi(z)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

This identity can be derived by starting on the right side of the equation and replacing each digamma function with its [series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula).

Using this identity, we get $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \text{Res} \left[f(z), i \pi \left(k+\frac{1}{2} \right)\right] = \frac{1}{i \pi} \frac{\psi \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{u}{\pi} \right) + \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{u}{\pi} \right) - 2 \psi \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)}{2u^{2}}.$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh x}{u^{2}+x^{2}} \frac{dx}{x} &= \frac{1}{2u^{2}} \left[\pi \tan u  + \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{u}{\pi} \right) + \psi \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{u}{\pi}\right) - 2 \,\psi \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \right] \\ &= \frac{1}{2u^{2}} \left[\pi \tan u  + \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{u}{\pi} \right) + \psi \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{u}{\pi}\right) +2 \gamma + 4 \log 2 \right] .\end{align}$$

Checking with Wolfram Alpha, this result appears to be correct for various values of $u$.

**EDIT**:

When $u = \pi$, the formula reduces to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh x}{\pi^{2}+x^{2}} \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{2}{\pi^{2}}.$$